# Pass VBA Variable in .html body

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am coding VBA to create an automated email using html format. I have couple of variable values from vba  that I need to pass in html coding. Long story short:

```
FullName = strfullname ' value for strfullname will be passed from another function

With objmail
  .bodyformat = olformathtml
   .htmlbody = "This is my fullname: (display the value of fullname ) "
end with
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FullName = strfullname ' value for strfullname will be passed from another function

With objmail
   .bodyformat = olformathtml
   .htmlbody = "This is my fullname: " & FullName
end with
```

Comment: Thank You so much!. That's all I wanted.